# Dictionary data is not properly appended to another dictionay

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas, odoo-10, pandas-groupby

Dictionary data is not properly appended to another dictionay. Here`acc_grp` is a grouped pandas data.

**acc_grp**

```
      amount_currency     balance    credit      debit     lid
ldate                                                               
2018-04-01              0.0  -27359.250  30219.25  1115.0000  643259
2018-04-02              0.0 -208574.742   5000.00  1194.0005  872275
```

Here `template_dict` is my dictionay.When I print `result` , both lines of my `acc_grp` is correctly available.

**Flow** (From Terminal)

**result (1st iteration)**

```
{'date': '2018-04-01', 'credit': 30219.25, 'balance': -29104.25, 'debit': 1115.0}
```

**template_dict**

```
{'code': u'300103', 'lines': [{'date': '2018-04-01', 'credit': 30219.25, 'balance': -29104.25, 'debit': 1115.0}], 'name': u'CASH COLLECTION'}
```

In first case,`result` is correctly appended to `template_dict`.

**result (2nd iteration)**

```
{'date': '2018-04-02', 'credit': 5000.0, 'balance': -3805.9994999999999, 'debit': 1194.0005}
```

**template_dict**

```
{'code': u'300103', 'lines': [{'date': '2018-04-02', 'credit': 5000.0, 'balance': -3805.9994999999999, 'debit': 1194.0005}, {'date': '2018-04-02', 'credit': 5000.0, 'balance': -3805.9994999999999, 'debit': 1194.0005}], 'name': u'CASH COLLECTION'}
```

Here when we look , `template_dict`'s `lines`'s value is supposed to be `result1` , `result2`  but the data is coming as `result2`,`result2`.

**code**

```
                result = {}
                template_dict = dict()
                template_dict['lines'] = []
                template_dict['code'] = line['code']
                template_dict['name'] = line['name']
                for index,row in acc_grp.iterrows():
                    balance=0
                    row.balance=row.debit.item()-row.credit.item()
                    result['date']=row.name
                    result['debit']=row.debit.item()
                    result['credit']=row.credit.item()
                    result['balance']=row.balance
                    print result
                    template_dict['lines'].append(result)
                    print template_dict
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create a new dictionary for each line. Otherwise, you're always changing the very same dictionary:

```
            ...
            for index,row in acc_grp.iterrows():
                result = {}  # Create a brand new dictionary
                balance=0
                row.balance=row.debit.item()-row.credit.item()
                result['date']=row.name
                ...
                template_dict['lines'].append(result)
```